# Bibliography format with multiple citations from same book? (APA)

Tags: citation-style

I'm writing a paper where I've included multiple citations from a book, each citation is not a direct quote from the text but rather a in-text citation.
According to APA guidelines, these citations should be at the end of the paraphrased text such as:

> My text here blob blob blob (Rubin, 2013).

Since these citations do not include page numbers (direct quotes do, according to APA guidelines) and I have three (so far) when I insert a bibliography with Word these look like this:

> Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, United States of America: Addison Wesley.
>   Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, United States of America: Addison Wesley.
>   Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, United States of America: Addison Wesley.

So, my question is: Is it okay to have these duplicate entries in the list of references/bibliography at the end of the document or should I add the page number to both in-text citations and references, even though they're not direct quotes within the document but in-text citations instead. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi, what did you find when you consulted the APA style guide?

Comment: @shoover Hi, I couldn't find anything related to list of references/bibliography. They give you guidelines for citations at the end of references/quotes, for example, put letters to distinguish them: `My text here blob blob blob (Rubin, 2013a)., My text here blob blob blob (Rubin, 2013b).`

Comment: I think References are in chapter 7 (APA 6).

Answer (score 1):

Normally duplicates are avoided. Also, your duplicates do not have a page reference and are therefore useless in this respect.

Whether or not you have to specify the page number, I would personally check with your supervisor to avoid misunderstandings.